# Restrict access to a bucket in GCS through terraform authoritatively using google_storage_bucket_iam_policy

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I have 2 email address - email_1 and email_2

I make email_1 admin on a bucket B1 authoritatively:

```
data "google_iam_policy" "app_engine_bucket_policy" {
  binding {
    role = "roles/storage.admin"
    members = [
      "user:email1@xyz.com",
    ]
  }
}

resource "google_storage_bucket_iam_policy" "apply_app_engine_bucket_policy" {
  bucket = google_storage_bucket.app_engine_bucket.name
  policy_data = data.google_iam_policy.app_engine_bucket_policy.policy_data
}
```

email_2 has a project wide role with storage.create permissions.
email_2 should not have any access to bucket B1.

```
resource "google_project_iam_member" "storage-create" {
  project = var.project_id
  role    = "storage.objects.create"
  member  = "user:email2@xyz.com"
}
```

But I was able to create new blob in bucket B1 through email_2.
How is `google_storage_bucket_iam_policy` authoritative if its not overriding other permissions on that bucket ?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of [storage_bucket_iam](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/google/latest/docs/resources/storage_bucket_iam) says that:

> Note:
>
> `google_storage_bucket_iam_policy` **cannot** be used in conjunction with : `google_storage_bucket_iam_binding` and `google_storage_bucket_iam_member` or they will fight over what your policy should be.

So depending on the order in which the resources are applied during a Terraform apply, if in your case the resource `google_project_iam_member` is applied later than your `google_storage_bucket_iam_policy`, the permissions to `email_2` are given too.

It is "authoritative" in a way that if the `google_storage_bucket_iam_policy` resource is applied later in a single Terraform apply, then the permissions given by the `google_project_iam_member` resource earlier in that apply will be removed.

---

PS I personally would prefer for Terraform to fail with a syntax error after a plan is created where such conflicting resources exist, but this is what we have now...